# .png not appearing on same height as my navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the logo to appear next to my navbar

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
   
<img src="../images/logo.png" alt="" width="90" height="90">
 <div class="hamburger-menu"><div class="rectangle">

        <ul class="navbar" id="nav">
            <li><a href="homepage.html" id="homepage">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
            <li><a href="information.html">INFORMATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="form.html">FORM</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a class="behandelingen" href="behandelingen.html">BEHANDELINGEN</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div></div>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*dit gaat over de indeling */
#nav ul .navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    float: center;

}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  li {
    float: left;
  }
  
  li a:not(.behandelingen, .logo) {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid;
  }
  
 /*Dit houd in dat de navbar knop de kleur #111 (zwart) word wanneer je er met je muis overheen gaat */
  li a:hover {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
  }

.rectangle:not(.img) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  width: 43%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I wanted to have my logo on the same height as my navbar which is not what happened. It's like the margin takes up the entire width of the page and im unable to put the logo where I wanted to.

Here you can see the problem:

[image: my problem]

Answer (score 1):

Add One additional div to the logo and nav bar to mange the same height and add the below css and code as per requirement

```css
#nav ul .navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    float: center;

}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;

}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a:not(.behandelingen, .logo) {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}

/*Dit houd in dat de navbar knop de kleur #111 (zwart) word wanneer je er met je muis overheen gaat */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.rectangle:not(.img) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    width: 43%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-main">
    <img src="../images/logo.png" alt="" width="90" height="90">
    <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <div class="rectangle">
            <ul class="navbar" id="nav">
                <li><a href="homepage.html" id="homepage">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
                <li><a href="information.html">INFORMATION</a></li>
                <li><a href="form.html">FORM</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a class="behandelingen" href="behandelingen.html">BEHANDELINGEN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```